# inserting failed info into a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I don't have an idea why pass it, the connection is fine, my table has `usuario` and `contraseña` and the name of the database is `Usuarios`, also
I put submit after of put information in the form and it doesn't mark me a mistake in the database.

Also I see all the code and I didn't found a mistake in the code to insert the data.

Another thing that I can say is that the method that I used for make the connection is PDO

```
<?php
require "./php/conectar.php";
$message = '';
if (!empty($_POST['usuario']) && !empty($_POST['contraseña'])) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, contraseña) VALUES (:usuario, :contraseña)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':usuario',$_POST['usuario']);
$password = password_hash($_POST['contraseña'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$stmt->bindParam(':contraseña',$_POST['contraseña']);
}
?>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+Paaji+2:wght@400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.js" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Formulario Inicio de sesión -->
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="formulario col-md-6">
          <h2 class="font-weight-light text-center mb-4">Iniciar sesion</h2>
          <form class="" action="login.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Dirección de email</label>
              <input
              maxlength="30"
                class="form-control form-control-lg"
                type="text"
                name="usuario"
                id="usuario"
                placeholder="Usuario"
                required
              />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Contraseña</label>
              <input
              maxlength="30"
                class="form-control form-control-lg"
                id="contraseña"
                name="contraseña"
                type="password"
                placeholder="contraseña"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <input
              class="form-control form-control-lg bg-primary font-weight-bold text-white"
              id="signin"
              type="submit"
              value="Iniciar sesión"
            />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="text-center reset-password">
        <a href="#" class="font-weight-bold">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: After you prepare and bind parameters, then what next

Comment: After you prepare and bind parameters, then what next

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code for it (too the code in the form), but it isn't works

```
if (!empty($_POST['usuario']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, contrasena) VALUES (:email, :password)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
$stmt->execute();
}
```